# OpenGL crash on Nexus5X

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-6.0-marshmallow, glsurfaceview, nexus-5x

My app uses Android Camera API (the old one) and GLSurfaceView.

It works on 90% of the devices (I actually tested it on a 100 different models!!!) but it crash on Nexus5X and Nexus6P.

I can see the following error on logcat:

```
W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES:4550>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

When I send the  Nexus5X crash report to google play, this is what I see:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:6.0.1/MMB29P/2473553:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'rev_1.0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 6443, tid: 6530, name: GLThread 68  >>> com.my.app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3b8
    r0 00000010  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000002
    r4 00001fbc  r5 80000000  r6 00000010  r7 00000000
    r8 00000000  r9 e11df2e0  sl 00000001  fp e11dd000
    ip de984270  sp e1844e3c  lr e9d4dbbd  pc e9dd6cf4  cpsr 80070030

backtrace:

    #00 pc 001b1cf4  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGfxMem::UpdateTimestampBucketId(EsxContext const*, unsigned int, EsxAccessType)+27)
    #01 pc 00128bb9  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::BucketRenderingCmds()+592)
    #02 pc 000dc2d9  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::BucketClearCmds(unsigned int*)+72)
    #03 pc 000dff89  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::ClearDirectly(EsxBltFill*, EsxColorClearData*, EsxBltDepthFill*, EsxBltDepthFill*)+3596)
    #04 pc 000e034d  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::ClearInternal(EsxBltFill*, EsxColorClearData*, EsxBltDepthFill*, EsxBltDepthFill*)+80)
    #05 pc 000e05ab  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::Clear(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, EsxClearValues*)+446)
    #06 pc 000c7f83  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlClear(unsigned int)+58)
    #07 pc 72104d39  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1ec9000)
```

The crash itself happens on `glFinish();` (I'll need to put half my project here to give more details).

Can anyone give me a clue where is the problem or how can I fix it?

Comment: Trace shows glClear, not glFinish...Is this the first gl call made after obtaining the context ?

Comment: That's a driver crash. Something is trying to dereference a bad address, which could be due to a driver bug, or due to the app passing a bad pointer in. Since it's a Nexus device you can file a bug on http://b.android.com/, but you'll need to provide a reproducible test case. One thing you can try is to scatter `glFinish()` throughout the code and see if you can narrow the crash -- remember that `glFinish()` just kicks off all of the queued-up work.